# How to filter example a retrieve data from phpmyadmin in rapidminer studio?

Tags: rapidminer

i want to filter my data from database in rapidminer studio. But when i give filter operator it doesn't work. It only works when i retrieve data from excel. So. What should i do to filter my data?

Comment: Hi Loka, could you please expand your question with much more details? It is very hard to help you without further information. What "doesn't work", when you use the filter operator? What is your process setup (probably even show your process as XML), how does your data look like, what do you expect to happen? Generally speaking: both "Read Excel" and "Read Database", when correctly configured, should return Example Sets, which then can be used as input to "Filter Examples". Maybe check, if "Read Database" returns the expected data and check your data types.

Comment: Adding to that: phpmyadmin is a webinterface to administrate a MySQL-database and should not be part of a regular database query.